# SQL Server CLR Stored Procedure JSON Parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, stored-procedures, clr

I've come across a scenario where I want to pass a large amount of data to a Stored Procedure for generating some dynamic SQL.

The data I want to pass is stored in this Json/C# class object that I use in my ASP.NET MVC web project.

```
[
 {
  "code":"ABC123",
  "Count": "12998",
  "Params":
  [
    {"name": "Recent", "value": "0-12m"},
    {"name": "Orders", "value": "1"}
  ]
 },
 {
  "code":"ABC124",
  "Count": "13998",
  "Params":
  [
   {"name": "Recent", "value": "0-12m"},
   {"name": "Orders", "value": "2"}
  ]
 },
 {
  "code":"ABC125",
  "Count": "7998",
  "Params":
  [
   {"name": "Recent", "value": "0-12m"},
   {"name": "Orders", "value": "3"}
  ]
 }
]
.....
```

Then use this text parameter to convert back to a JSON object, I use this in an action filter to convert it to an object.

```
public class ObjectFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public string Param { get; set; }

    public Type RootType { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        if ((filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType ?? string.Empty).Contains("application/json"))
        {

            object o =

            new DataContractJsonSerializer(RootType).ReadObject(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Rewind InputStream for other filters

            filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = o;

        }

        else
        {

            var xmlRoot = XElement.Load(new StreamReader(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream,

            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentEncoding));

            object o = new XmlSerializer(RootType).Deserialize(xmlRoot.CreateReader());

            filterContext.ActionParameters[Param] = o;

        }

    }
```

}

and then use C# etc in my CLR Stored Procedure to create a SQL statement such as:

```
UPDATE [Sample]
SET [Field] =
CASE
WHEN [Recent] = "0-12m" AND [Orders] = "1" THEN "ABC123"
WHEN [Recent] = "0-12m" AND [Orders] = "2" THEN "ABC124"
WHEN [Recent] = "0-12m" AND [Orders] = "3" THEN "ABC125"
...
```

Is this possible and has anyone ever done anything like this. I've seen a few posts on using a XML parameter but none using a varchar parameter using de-serialized (?) json.

Comment: This might help [Consuming JSON Strings in SQL Server](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/?utm_source=simpletalk&utm_medium=email-main&utm_content=JSON-20101116&utm_campaign=SQL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to use my code to parse a JSON string parameter but the required namespaces are not available in a SQL CLR project and I have therefore switched to the documented Xml parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible; please see the canonical reference on dynamic SQL: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can only use an unsafe assembly such as DataContractJsonSerializer if you're building an unsafe assembly yourself.  The other option is to skip the reference to and use of the unsafe assembly and write your own JSON parse code (or copy it from someone else.)