# Array in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

I know this question has been asked many times but I am not a PRO in SQL so i need a little help.

I have two tables - `Person` and `ContactNumber`. A person can have many contact numbers which will need to all be inserted into the `ContactNumber` table each time I make a save. I was thinking about having an array/collection of contact numbers, with `Person id` that will be generated automatically when I insert.

What I am looking for help on is, how can I achieve that? The solutions I found on the net all use  XML/string delimiter but I think in my case it will not work. Or maybe it can but I am not exactly sure how to incorporate this into my code.

If some one have the solution please Post the code too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have a table "ContactNumber" that is a child of "Person". That is, you don't store them as CSV, XML or whatever. One row per number.

Simple example

Person. Primary key is PersonID 
`PersonID, Firstname, Lastname, Gender, ...`

NumberType. Primary key is NumberType. Stores things like "Mobile", "Home" etc
 
`NumberTypeID, NumberType`

ContactNumbers. Primary key is both PersonID, NumberType 
You have foreign keys to both Person and NumberType 
`PersonID, NumberTypeID, PhoneNumber`

Edit, after comment:

With SQL Server 2008 you can use table valued parameters to send arrays to SQL Server. The most thorough article is ["Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2008"](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog,

Also, don't use @@IDENTITY: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is safer

Comment: i have made all these tables but yet it doesnt solve the issue. i m taking values from WebPage in there user can have 1 Ph.Number or many Ph.Number so i have to store that array of Ph.Numbers against the person ID that i will get through @@Identity. how can i send array/collection in SQL Stored Procedure Parameter. and then can store those values against single Personid or in ur case against NumberType id

Answer (score 0):

This would involve CLR user-defined types existing both in client and on server.

See also [SQL Server CLR Stored Procedure JSON Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431975/sql-server-clr-stored-procedure-json-parameter)

Caveat: this is new OOP / CLR support in the DB and is not standard SQL way of doing things.